# How to stop mouse from zooming in when trying to scroll down

Tags: mouse, macos

In trying to zoom down, the mouse has taken to zooming in his entire screen. As in, magnifying the entire screen, focusing on where the cursor is.

This happens when quickly scrolling down a few times. Google isn't coming up with anything good so I'm asking here.

Comment: Mine started zooming instead of scrolling. I couldn't make the mouse do anything else. I hit the ESC button and it went back to normal. I'm kinda wondering how to turn it back on now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but should be 
System preferences -> Accessibility -> Zoom -> Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom (or similar, I got it in italian) that should be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the Ctrl key being pressed, which enabled the zoom.